# Stylesheets not working in asp.net site under iis7.5

Tags: iis-7.5

Hi
My app works fine when run from VSWEBdeveloper10.
But from IIS7.5, it doesnt apply stylesheets at all.
I have checked paths.
When I try to access stylesheet directly from browser, it redirects to the app's login page, and after logging in, it shows a weird sqlserver error.
Dont know how it relates CSS to sqlserver.
Note that, app works perfectly fine with VSWebDeveloper2010 while debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the application as a virtual directory under the default website on port 80?  If so, then your stylesheets and images are possibly not being found because the pathing is now incorrect according to the root of the default website.  What works is if you actually create a new website on a separate port.  Then your stylesheets will be found without a problem.